# How to make two armature actions into one action?

Tags: modeling

I have 2 animations one for each arm and I can't go back because I made them separate from the beginning. Help?

Comment: The 1st armature is separate from the second and is a parent of the 1st mesh, and vice versa.

Comment: Do you mean that there are two .blend files and each has one animated arm?

Answer (score 2):

Armatures can be joined together using Ctrl-J. You can also copy keyframes between actions using Key > Copy Keyframes. So you could copy the keyframes from one arm, join it to the other, and paste the keyframes to the other's action.