# How do I join bones and keep the animations?

Tags: animation, bones

I am trying to make a mechanical spider and I have make a leg with bones animation, which I have duplicated, but I need to have it joined as one object so I can export it to unity. When I try only one of the animations is kept how do I keep all animations?

Comment: Can you provide a [file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)  and / or a screenshot or two.?  A biped rig will have bones "UpperLeg.L" and "UpperLeg.R".  What naming convention will you use for spider?  As it is now, (with one leg) let's say you have a bone named "Bone", when you join to have 8 legs, you will have "Bone.001" ... etc.  but your one leg animation only animates "Bone",  AFAIK joining doesn't also create new fcurves for the added bones with new names.  Can be done with a script.

Comment: I have changed the names of the bones and vertex groups to be different which allows me to join the bones and mesh and keep the correct vertex groups, but only one animation is kept

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28562/15543)

Comment: When I try and copy paste the key-frames it looks real messed up. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4135" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4135/)